# php code not working on server, works in localhost

Tags: php

My codes was working perfectly fine on localhost and i decide to shift it into the server for final test, and found out that it suddenly doesn't work. May i know what was wrong with it?

```
else if ($password == $passwordcfm) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (username, password, printName, email, location, gender,     class, contact)
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$realName', '$email', '$address', '$sex', 'ORD', '$noNumber')");
echo "Successfully registered as member.<br><br> <a href='index.php'>Click Here to return     to Index</a>.";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Also i have like another php code that involves phpmailer... It works on my localhost side, and proceed to fail on the server... Also it seems that the server doesn't read those "mysqli" stuffs... only "mysql".

Comment: try to `die(mysql_error())` along with your query like `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` this will print error if any in your query

Comment: Prohibit use of MYSQL. Prefer MySQLI or PDO. Ask your server's admin to install the required libraries.

Comment: I wished i could contact the server admin regarding this. My boss bought this random server hosting from some IDONEVENKNOWWHATISTHIS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following :

Is your connection to datavase correct in your server code ?

Is SMTP setup in your server for PHPmailer ?

Is mysqli enabled in your apache ? Check for details: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/how-want-enable-mysqli-142737.html

Kindly comment if you still have any more issues!

Comment: i was able to do basic checks from the database, log-in functions and even updates into the database. It's just this (INSERT) thing.

I'm not sure if the server is set up for PHPMailer, but i am able to send mail using that SMTP when i use my codes locally.

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (username, password, printName, email, location, gender,     class, contact)
VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$realName."', '".$email."', '".$address."', '".$sex."', 'ORD', '".$noNumber."')");`

Make your code as above

Comment: Also echo $password and $passwordcfm to see if they are same. Put a echo "something" in `else if` block to see if program control is coming there.

Answer (score 0):

else if ($password == $passwordcfm) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (username, password, printName, email, location, gender,     class, contact)
VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$realName."', '".$email."', '".$address."', '".$sex."', '".ORD."', '".$noNumber."')");
echo "Successfully registered as member.
 Click Here to return     to Index.";
}
mysql_close($con);